# Build EAR in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

i created an EAR-Application in Eclipse Indigo and compile it via "run on server". All works well but i dont see the compile errors in the console. How can i make it visible?
Is where any way to compile an ear without having an AS running?

thx
BJ

Answer (score 1):

Your code is compiled in the background, not when you invoke "run on server". To see compilation problems, you need to look in the Problems View rather than the console. If the Problems View is not visible in your current perspective, use "Window -> Show View" menu to find it.

To create a .ear file, you can use the "File -> Export -> Java EE -> EAR file" wizard.

Comment: i wasnt sure if the build in eclipse compiler does the same as the compiler in "run on server".

Comment: It is a good question. There is no compilation during "run on server". Previously compiled artifacts are assembled into the structure that the server can run and then published via server's API. What exactly happens during assemble and publish steps is varies from server to server. A common/simple strategy is to copy static content and compiled artifacts into a staging directory that is shaped like EAR content.